# How I can get the albums/photos of a group on facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a PHP script which gets the posts from the group, but I want to get the albums too to can show them on a webpage, I been searching everywhere for a solution but I cant find one, most of them dont work anymore because there is no album connection in the group API anymore.So what I can use to get the albums from a group... or its imposible to get that ?